# Publishing a web role with node.js and msnodesql gives sql error IM002

Tags: node.js, azure-sql-database

I am publishing a node app using Publish-AzureServiceProject. Everything that is not related to sql server is working ok. Upon running a query though, I get the error IM002 ("Data source name not found and no default driver specified")

it looks like the proper drivers are not installed in the production environment? After all I had the same problem when running the service locally, but everything was sorted out after I installed driver from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065)

So the question is, do I need to install the driver on production as well, and if so, how?

Comment: What's your connection string? What's your package.json?

Comment: @SLaks: the package.json under the role is: {"author":"","name":"uRole","version":"0.0.0","dependencies":{},"devDependencies":{},"optionalDependencies":{},"engines":{"node":"0.6.20","iisnode":"0.1.21"}}. the connection string is "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=tcp:eca66dmwe0.database.windows.net,1433;Database=DB;Uid=xx@XX;Pwd=XXX;Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30;"

Answer (score 0):

That was indeed the problem. I logged in with remote desktop into the role and installed SQL native client.